# JSon Output jQuery div Containers with Children & Attributes

Tags: javascript, json, save, jsplumb

I am currently working with jsPlumb & got stuck at saving & loading the containers. I figured out how to save the endpoints, connections & positions.
But I can't figure out, how to save the div containers, including their attributes, children & the children's attrubites.
Here's a snippet of the containers, any ideas how to stringify them?

```html
<div class="window main node ui-draggable _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_" id="maincontainer1" data-nodetype="main" style="left: 663px; top: 200px; width: 230px; height: 200px;">
 <div class="ctrl_container">
  <div class="button_rm">x</div>
 </div>
 <div class="layer" id="layercontainer1_1" style="height: 80px; width: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;">
  <div class="window filter node" style="left:25px; top:5px;" name="3#2#ABC#" id="filtercontainer2_1_1">
   <div class="ctrl_container">
    <a class="filter_caption edit" href="#">Edit</a>
    <div class="button_rm">x</div>
   </div>
   <div class="details_container">
    <span id="filter_label" class="filter_label jtextfill" style="font-size: 22px;">PrimarySupportGrp =  123</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="layer" id="layercontainer1_2" style="height: 90px; width: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);"><div class="line-separator"></div>
  <div class="window filter node" style="left:25px; top:5px;" name="5#4#Yes#" id="filtercontainer2_2_1">
   <div class="ctrl_container">
    <a class="filter_caption edit" href="#">Edit</a>
    <div class="button_rm">x</div>
   </div>
   <div style="" class="details_container">
    <span id="filter_label" class="filter_label jtextfill" style="font-size: 14px;"> Site   &gt;  Yes</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suggest saving the complete children hierarchy, but if you want - why not use `.html()`

```
var data = [];
$(".layer").each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    data.push(html);
});
```

OR

Just save what is required to re-render them at the correct position - left, top etc.

```
for(var i=0 ; i<length; i++){
  var layerTemplate = "...div template html goes here";
  var $layerTemplate = $(layerTemplate);
  $layerTemplate.css({top : data[i].top , left : data[i].left});
  $("#maincontainer1").append($layerTemplate);
}
```

Some time back I wrote a script for saving & re-rendering jsPlumb - https://github.com/nitinsurana/jsPlumb-Persistence